# How to fix 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)'

Tags: c

I'm trying to solve my homework.
The question is asking to implement the function count(FILE *fp) that takes as input a text file and returns the number of sentences in the file.

But the output is showing an error 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)'.

```c
int count(FILE *fp)
{

int count=0;

    char word[256];
    while(fscanf(fp,"%s",word)!=EOF)
    {
        if(word[strlen(word)-1]=='.')
        {
            count+=1;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: You tagged the question with C++ but you use C functions types. Is there a reason? A segmentation fault is caused by writing into an array out-of-bounds. This could happen when write the 256th character into words. You can analyze the core dump with your debugger to see where your program terminated.

Comment: I do not find any error here. Segmentation should not come from this function. Please check rest of your code. You can paste here as well.

Comment: Here if strlen(word) returns a value grater than 256 (Meaning you have a sentence with more than 256 characters) you would get a segmentation fault.

Comment: this happens when you are trying to access array index which doesn't exist...

Answer (score 1):

(If you're on Linux, compile your program with the `-fsanitize=address` flag. If your program runs into a segmentation fault, it will tell you in excruciating detail what went wrong).

If your file contains a "word" (sequence of characters which are not whitespace) longer than 256 characters (maybe the text is in German, or the text of Mary Poppins), `fscanf` will write that many characters into `word`, overflowing it. This can lead to segmentation faults.

You can prevent that by limiting the number of characters `fscanf` will try to write:

```
fscanf(fp,"%256s",word);
```

This may split a "word" into two or more parts, but only the last part with the dot will be counted (unless the word looks like "twohundred-and-fifty-five-characters.some-more").

Note that `fscanf` can return zero if no fields were stored, although this appears impossible when `%s` is used. In this case, you'll be applying `strlen` to uninitialized memory, which can lead to segmentation faults.

Also, if `fscanf` gives back an empty string (also appears impossible), `strlen` will return zero, and you'll try to read `word[-1]`, that is, a buffer underrun. You should check the result of `strlen` before subtracting from it.

Answer (score -1):

Here if strlen(word) returns a value grater than 256 (Meaning you have a sentence with more than 256 characters) you would get a segmentation fault.

You can find the solution in Bulletmagnet's answer

Comment: -2 is wrong. The \0 is not counted by `strlen`. strlen("ab.") is 3. Offset 0 is 'a', offset 1 is 'b' and offset 2 (strlen-1) is '.'

Comment: I may be wrong. Have you tested the code? Maybe it is counting newline.

Comment: I did test the code, as opposed to you. I also read the man page for `strlen`.

Comment: Sorry, I saw `fscanf` where you wrote `fgets`. However, your program is wrong. It will not count a sentence if the input line is "This is a sentence. This is not" because it will only detect periods at the end of the line, not inside. `fgets` and `fscanf` perform very different tasks and you can't just substitute one with another. `fscanf` returns each "word" (sequence of non-whitespace characters) whereas `fgets` returns an entire line. If you use `fgets` to get a whole line, you should use `sscanf` afterwards to separate words.

Comment: @Bulletmagnet You are right on that one. I have deleted that part of the answer